# Curl doesn't work properly with 2G and 3G for downloading a small file with HTTP protocol

Tags: curl

I have a code with C/C++ in Android to download small files with Curl. I don't have any problem when I am working with 4G and 5G. But when I have a weak Internet downloading the small files does not work properly.